# print hash key with converted hash xml simple

Tags: xml, perl, hash, xml-simple

I am new with perl and i want to get keys of Hash table generated using `XML::SIMPLE` module 
like this

```
$data = $xml->XMLin("tp.xml");
```

Here is the structure generated

```
$VAR1 = {
      'technical-profile' => {
                             'WEB' => {
                                      'mandatory-param' => {
                                                           'value' => 'high',
                                                           'name' => 'screenCapability',
                                                           'case-sensitive' => 'no'
                                                         }
                                    },
                             'WAP/PDA' => {
                                          'description' => 'wap/sparphone',
                                          'mandatory-param' => {
                                                               'value' => 'low|intermediate',
                                                               'name' => 'screenCapability',
                                                               'case-sensitive' => 'no'
                                                             }
                                        },
                             'WAP' => {
                                      'description' => 'wap/sparphone',
                                      'mandatory-param' => {
                                                           'value' => 'low',
                                                           'name' => 'screenCapability',
                                                           'case-sensitive' => 'no'
                                                         }
                                    }
                           }
    };
```

I tried this

```
print "Key: $_" foreach (keys%data);
```

but i get nothing; i want to print the `WEB` `WAP/PDA` and `WAP` how is that possible please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and every perl script you make.

If you had done that you would've gotten the following error:

```
Global symbol "%data" requires explicit package name
```

Your data is a hashref assigned to `$data`.  Therefore to see the keys of it, you do the following:

```
print "Key: $_\n" for keys %$data;
```

For the three values on the second level of your hash, you'd use the following:

```
print "Key: $_\n" for keys %{$data->{technical-profile}};
```

Should output (in random order):

```
Key: WEB
Key: WAP/PDA
Key: WAP
```